# Change value in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog, and I want to change the value of a variable, which is extracted from a list. Initially, the variable is `n`, then on some occasions I would like to change it to `a`. But using `(is)/2` won't work because it only operates on numbers.

Is there an easy way to do this? Suppose my code looks something like this:

```
change([H|T]) :- set H to a,change(T).
change([]).
```

Notice `H` has already been set to `n`, so the goal `H = a` fails because `n` and `a` cannot be unified.

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying to write to establish some context? `is/2` is not for "assignment" anyway. It's for arithmetic expression evaluation. In Prolog you have *predicates* not *functions* (not the same thing behaviorally), and there is *unification* (using `=/2`) not *assignment* (also not the same thing behaviorally).

Comment: `set H to a` is not valid Prolog syntax. Do you have a Prolog book or have you been through a basic Prolog tutorial? And if `H` already has a value, then you cannot assign a new value to `H` in that context. To change a list like that, you need to generate a new list, `change(OldList, NewList)`.

Comment: Really, why can't we assign a new value to it? That seems inconvenient

Comment: Because, as I mentioned, it's not assignment, it's unification. Prolog isn't a procedural, imperative language. It's declarative and uses logic and backtracking. Prolog predicates work to determine if a query is true and, if it can't, it fails. When a variable is *unified*, the logic requires that its value not be changed (except through backtracking) or the logic would become invalid. Imagine having a logical argument with someone who kept changing the assumptions. You wouldn't get very far. When you understand Prolog, it's actually quite convenient that variables can't be changed. :)

Comment: I would highly recommend getting a good Prolog book, such as *The Art Of Prolog*, if you want to learn the language. Many beginners try to do in Prolog things they do in other languages and in the same way, but it's not the same kind of tool. So the beginner gets frustrated and thinks the language is restrictive or too peculiar because it doesn't fit their paradyme for programming. But study it a bit, and you'll understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting the key issue when learning prolog that it doesn't work like procedural languages.

A variable in prolog is a variable in the sense that it can have any value, but at any point in a computation if the variable has been unified then it cannot change unless prolog backtracks.

So, you cannot simply take a list, such as `[m, n, o, p]` and change it to be `[m, a, o, p]`. You have to construct a new list.

Here's how:

```
replace_n_with_a([], []).
replace_n_with_a([n|X], [a|Y]) :- replace_n_with_a(X, Y).
replace_n_with_a([H|X], [H|Y]) :- H \= n, replace_n_with_a(X, Y).
```

These three predicates take a list and build a new one, but swap `n` for `a` whenever it finds it. The original list hasn't changed, but I now have a new one that I can pass to the next part of my code.

To run the above code you may have this:

```
?- replace_n_with_a([m, n, o, p], Xs), write(Xs), nl.
```

I get this result:

```
[m, a, o, p]
Yes.
```