# Updating variables in matrix in prolog

Tags: prolog

How does the element in matrix be updated in prolog?

```
L=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
nth0(1,L,Row).
Row=[4,5,6]
nth0(1,Row,8].
false !
```

Comment: In prolog, variables rarely be 'updated' but usually be unified. The process of being unified is call unification. Because of unification, comparing with other programming language, such as C/C++, Java, Python, you could find prolog has unconventional behaviors of variables.  [The first answer might help you rethink your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503336/change-value-in-prolog?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: `nth0(1, Row, 8)` fails because element number 1 in the list `Row` is not 8, it's 5. Prolog is telling you it cannot make them match. What you need to do is build a new matrix with the replaced element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nth0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth0/4)/4: for instance

```
update_mat_rc(Mc,R,C,V,Mu) :-
    nth0(R,Mc,Rc,Mt),
    nth0(C,Rc,_,Rt),
    nth0(C,Ru,V,Rt),
    nth0(R,Mu,Ru,Mt).

?- update_mat_rc([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],1,1,x,M).
M = [[1, 2, 3], [4, x, 6], [7, 8, 9]].
```

Note the order and naming of variables passed to nth0/4.

I have suffixed variables with *c* (like `Mc`,`Rc`) to mean *current*, with *t* to mean *temporary*, with *u* to mean *updated*.